# Use of undeclared identifier error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am trying to set up a running loop, and to do so I've the following code:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:a forMode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode];
```

However I get an error saying "Use of undeclared identifier 'a'". I have both of these methods declared in my header and main file:

```
//AppController.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface AppController : NSObject
- (IBAction) startLoop: (id)sender;
- (void) a: (id)sender;
@end

//AppController.m
#import "AppController.h"
@implementation AppController
-(IBAction) startLoop: (id) sender {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:a forMode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode];
}
-(void) a: (id) sender {
    //Code here 
}
@end
```

I'm new to Objective-C so I apologise in advance for any silly mistakes, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addTimer::` method wants its first parameter to be a NSTimer object.  The only thing visible in your code that's (almost) called `a` is not only not a NSTimer, but not an object at all.  It's a method.  Do you have a timer created somewhere that you intended to use?

(Technically, the method's name is `a:` rather than `a`.)